# Search only childs and specifics grandchildren

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm looking for an expression with xapth to pass at two level which are : childs nodes and "specifics  grandchildren nodes" :

For instance :

```
<nodeLevel_1>

  <nodeLevel_1.1 value="a" />

  <nodeLevel_1.2 value="b" />

  <nodeLevel_1.3>
     <nodeLevel_1.3.1 value="c" />
  </nodeLevel_1.3>

</nodeLevel_1>

<nodeLevel_2>
   ....
```

Here im trying to reach an attribute: 
`nodeLevel_1.1/@value` and `nodeLevel_1.3.1/@value`

but without any pass by `nodeLevel_1.2/@value`.

I tried to use : `descendant::nodeLevel1/@value`
but with this xpath i got @value attribute of nodeLevel_1.2 and i don't want this.

Is there a way to manage this case with xpath ? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for the tag name not equal to `nodeLevel_1.2`.

Tested using `xmllint`:

```
$ cat input.xml
<nodeLevel_1>
  <nodeLevel_1.1 value="a" />
  <nodeLevel_1.2 value="b" />
  <nodeLevel_1.3>
     <nodeLevel_1.3.1 value="c" />
  </nodeLevel_1.3>
</nodeLevel_1>

$ xmllint input.xml --xpath "//descendant::nodeLevel_1/*[not(self::nodeLevel_1.2)]/@value"
 value="a"
```